# Change Button Text via PHP | WooCoommerce

Tags: php, css, button, woocommerce

Hello I have a button in WooCoommerce. I would like to translate the button. But I can't do that via LocoTranslate or anything else. Is there any PHP function to replace button texts without ID?

Here you can see the [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNfgL.png)

Here you can see the [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vduqa.png) in the frontend

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $args = array() ) {
  global $product;

  if ( $product ) {
    $defaults = array(
      'quantity'   => 1,
      'class'      => implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
        'button',
        'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
      ) ) ),
      'attributes' => array(
        'data-product_id'  => $product->get_id(),
        'data-product_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
        'aria-label'       => $product->add_to_cart_description(),
        'rel'              => 'nofollow',
      ),
    );

    $args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ), $product );

    wc_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php', $args );
  }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
        return __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Comment: Hey Erhan thank you! But it didn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('gettext_woocommerce', 'rename_button_text_wc', 10, 3);

function rename_button_text_wc($translated_text, $text, $text_domain) {
    // bail if admin page or not modifying frontend woocommerce text.
    if (is_admin() || 'woocommerce' !== $text_domain) {
        return $translated_text;
    }

    if ('Check Out All' === $text) {
        $translated_text = 'Checkout';
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```